# How to add HTML5 files to Android programatically?

Tags: android, html

I developed a game in HTML5. It contains JavaScript and HTML files. Now I want to add them to my Android app. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need To add `Webview` to have `HTML5`  Files to be loaded this can be done like this

```
 public class HelloWebView extends Activity { 

     WebView webview;

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
     setContentView(R.layout.main); 

     webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); 
     webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
     webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient()); 
     webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html"); 
     WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings(); 
     settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
     settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true); 
     String databasePath = this.getApplicationContext().getDir("database",  Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath(); 
     settings.setDatabasePath(databasePath);
     webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() { 
     public void onExceededDatabaseQuota(String url, String databaseIdentifier, long currentQuota, long estimatedSize, long totalUsedQuota, WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater) { 
            quotaUpdater.updateQuota(5 * 1024 * 1024); 
        } 
    }); 
    }
```

And place your `HTML5` files inside assets.

Answer (score 1):

**Android Developer Website** should be the first thing comes to mind. Check [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) Page.

For tutorial you can check :
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can have webview within your android device which load the page that host your html5 game.

Comment: didnot get you @Quynh Nguyen could you explain it or can you provide any source link or example for it

Comment: Late to response but Alice provided a perfect answer! Just right below my post :)